# Possibilities of tracking an object after detection(feature based object recognition)

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, video-tracking

I am working on object recognition in android. So far i am able to detect/recognise objects at a frame rate of 5-8 fps. Now,i want to track the detected object in subsequent frames.

short summary of what i have done so far.

1. capture and store the object of interest in external directory of the phone as an image.
2. Detect and extract the feature points(used ORB feature detector and descriptor).
3. Perform matching and draw rectangular box around the detected object(Homography).

example of the object which is detected.
[image]

Now, after performing homography, I intend to track the object in subsequent frames.
Which are the possible algorithms which can do this(Is this method of tracking after detection possible)?.I have gone through particle filter and kalman filter based tracking, but unable to understand which parameters need to be passed to instantiate tracking after homography.
Any reference to tracking algorithms,documents, example codes in openCV would be helpful.

**EDIT**

```
for(int i_gm=0; i_gm<goodmatches.size(); i_gm++)
        {

            scene.push_back(v1[goodmatches[i_gm].trainIdx].pt);
            objnew.x+=scene[i_gm].x;
            objnew.y+=scene[i_gm].y;
        }
   // calculation of centroid of the object.
      objnew.x/=scene.size();
      objnew.y/=scene.size();

   // Kalman predict and correct.
        KfMeasurement.setTo(Scalar(0));
        Kf.statePre.at<float>(0)=objnew.x;
        Kf.statePre.at<float>(1)=objnew.y;
        Kf.statePre.at<float>(2)=0;
        Kf.statePre.at<float>(3)=0;
        Kf.transitionMatrix=(Mat_<float>(4,4)<< 1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1);
        setIdentity(Kf.measurementMatrix);
        setIdentity(Kf.processNoiseCov,Scalar::all(1e-5));
        setIdentity(Kf.measurementNoiseCov,Scalar::all(1e-1));
        setIdentity(Kf.errorCovPost,Scalar::all(.1));
        Mat prediction = Kf.predict();
        Point predictPt(prediction.at<float>(0),prediction.at<float>(1));
        KfMeasurement(0)=objnew.x;
        KfMeasurement(1)=objnew.y;
        Point measPt(KfMeasurement(0),KfMeasurement(1));
        Mat estimated=Kf.correct(KfMeasurement);
        Point statept(estimated.at<float>(0),estimated.at<float>(1));
        circle( kalRgba,statept,50, Scalar(255,255,255), 3 );
        circle(kalRgba, measPt, 10,Scalar(10,10,255), 3 );
        circle( kalRgba,predictPt,10, Scalar(100,255,0), 3 );
```

Comment: in general, optical flow algorithms are used for visual tracking. if you want to use your own detection as a measurement step, you can use kalman filter with priori info=current center of rect, measurement info=next center of rect. please check both: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520711/2d-motion-estimation-using-python-opencv-kalman-filtering/17532947#17532947, http://epubs.surrey.ac.uk/713800/1/Kalal-PAMI-2011(1).pdf

Comment: Thanks @CanberkBaci .I will try your suggestion and post the results I get.

Comment: You can always apply simple tracking on the corners of the bounding box and the centroid.

Comment: @GilLevi Can you please explain what do you mean by simple tracking (specific algorithm or any papers)?. I implemented kalman filter but it was not  much of an optimization to increase the frame rates  since i had to initiate the  process of detection again to get new points of the object when it is moved and then give the new points to kalman filter. I am now looking at the code of openTLD, its seems to be interesting but a bit complicated too. Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: @Darshan, Sorry for the late response. Can you please explain what was the problem with Kalman Filter, I didn't follow.

Comment: @GilLevi :  I have updated my question with code, might be helpful for you to understand my problem. The problem is that, to get the updated points objnew.x and objnew.y in every frame, I have to reinitialize the recognition process which is not helping the cause of increasing the frame rates. Is there any other way to do this?. Is my implementation wrong ? please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: @Darshan, sorry again for the late response. You can predict the location of the object in the next frame and then, in the following frame, search for the object in some region around the predicted location. Does that help?

Comment: "search for the object in some region around the predicted location",how to do this ? define ROI and search in that location or perhaps do window search method in subsequent frames?. Thanks for the help . I have started integrating TLD in my app, but would still like to try out your suggestions on Kalaman filters.